# Nexus version Upgrade from 3.20.1 to 3.22.1-02

Tags: nexus, nexus3

After upgrading nexus version up to 3.22.1-02 some users have informed that some of old libraries in pypi proxy repository get deleted.Do you have any idea about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The cause is likely https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-22770.  Unfortunately a bug was found with the implemented automatic rebuild: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-23417.  So if things don't appear in browse, you would need to run "Repair - Rebuild repository browse" against the repository (or repositories) again.

Note if this is the issue you are having, there should be no impact to your usage of PyPI, it's just a display issue.